# Incorrect argument in SocketIOClient socket.io swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to port an old app based on socket.io that used to work.
I'm compiling with swift 4 and using version 13.4.0 (the last one before v14 which requires minimum version of the client is Swift 4.2) of socket.io.
I use the example from socket.io GitHub readme file available for [this branch](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/tree/1.0-swift4) which is:

```
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)])
```

When I try to compile with Xcode 11.3.1, I have the following error:
`Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'socketURL:config:', expected 'manager:nsp:')` with the suggestion to fix it by replacing `'socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config'` with `'manager: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, nsp'`. If I choose this way, which is different from what is suggested on the readme file, I have this new error: `Argument type 'URL' does not conform to expected type 'SocketManagerSpec'`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how I can fix that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't read the only the ReadMe. Find the declaration of that method, and its others sub declaration (of `SocketIOClientCOnfiguration` for instance) Try: `let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: SocketIOClientConfiguration.init(arrayLiteral: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)]))`?

Answer (score 0):

The initializer you are using isn't correct for a `SocketIOClient`, but `SocketManager`.

So you can do something like this found in the [Socket.IO-Client-Swift repo](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift):

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket
```